# discord webhook help javascript

Tags: javascript, post, discord, webhooks

I am trying post a Webhook using javascript. My goal is to allow the user to type their Webhook URL, and when they click "`send`", it should send my Webhook message.

I am new to Javascript and not sure what I am doing wrong!

#### *HTML:*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background">
        <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="paste webhook here">
        <button id="send" onclick="sendMessage()">send</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

#### *Javascript:*

```js
function sendMessage() {

    let grabData = document.getElementById("input");
    
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", grabData);


    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    
    var myEmbed = {
      title: "Test Successful! ",
      color: hexToDecimal("#2A67E8")
    }
    
    var params = {
      username: "objexive",
      avatar_url: "https://i.ibb.co/7X9szNY/exhbition-webhookicon1.png",
      embeds: [ myEmbed ]
    }
    
    request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    
    // function that converts a color HEX to a valid Discord color
    function hexToDecimal(hex) {
      return parseInt(hex.replace("#",""), 16)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone that has the problem, it was a very simple fix. add `.value` to "grabData"